# why nginx do not deny request when semicolon is in url?

Tags: security, nginx, url, reverse-proxy, directory-traversal

I have a nginx.conf as follows:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    # some other ssl config

    server_name home.aaa.com;

    # some access_log and error_log config

    location /actuator/ {
        allow 10.1.1.0/24;
        deny all;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.1.1:8989;
    }   

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.1.1.1:8989;
    }   
}
```

When I access https://home.aaa.com/actuator/prometheus, nginx deny this request and return 403, this is what I expect.

When I access https://home.aaa.com/actuator/prometheus;%2f..%2f..//, nginx output a new line in access.log:

1.203.146.132 - - [15/Jan/2024:11:00:55 +0800] "GET /actuator/prometheus;%2f..%2f..// HTTP/1.1" 200 7889841 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0" "-" https "home.aaa.com" "1.025" "0.270" "10.1.1.1:8989"

and there is not a log in nginx error_log. But I expect nginx deny this request too.

I do not know why the second request was proxied to the backend server, and how can I debug this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url `https://home.aaa.com/actuator/prometheus;%2f..%2f..//` after url decode is `https://home.aaa.com/actuator/prometheus;/../..//`. Which will in the nginx `$uri` valable will be `/`. Then it not match the `location /actuator/`.

Here is the illustration,

```
#nginx config
location /actuator/ {
     return 403 $uri;
}   

location / {
    return 200 $uri;
}
```

And the curl result

```
$ curl -sS 'xxxx/actuator/prometheus;%2f..%2f..//'
/

$ curl -sS 'xxxx/actuator/prometheus'
/actuator/prometheus
```

Comment: why in this case `$uri` is `/`

Comment: `..` refer to the paraent folder, so in your case `../../` refer to the `/`

Comment: What role does the semicolon play here? When I remove the semicolon, this request `https://home.aaa.com/actuator/prometheus%2f..%2f..//` returns 400.

Comment: In my case there is no difference with or without the `;`, `$ curl -sS 'xxxx/actuator/prometheus%2f..%2f..//' ` and returns `/`

Comment: Nginx treats `;` as a regular character, while java treats it as parameter delimeter. 

So nginx looks `/actuator/prometheus%2f..%2f..//` like `/`, while java looks it like `/actuator/prometheus`

Refer to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/251723/semicolons-relation-with-reverse-proxy

Comment: To nginx there is no difference with or without the `;`, To java `;` is  necessary. Without `;` java returns 400

Comment: Thanks @LF-DevJourney,  You've resolved my confusion, sending you a big hug!!!